# Neo4j Apoc Trigger in "Phase: After" Never Ends

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I've ran into an unexpected behavior and can't figure out what's the source of it. I'm using apoc 3.5.0.9, and I'm trying to have a trigger in **"phase: after"** that creates a relationship with the node that has been updated with some other node, but this causes the trigger to never end.

For instance, with this dataset:

```
CREATE (:TEST {name:'x', _executed:0});
CREATE (:TEST {name:'y', _executed:0});
```

And this simple trigger:

```
CALL apoc.trigger.add('triggerTest','UNWIND apoc.trigger.propertiesByKey({assignedNodeProperties},"_executed") as prop
    WITH prop.node as n
    CREATE (z:SON {father:id(n)})
    CREATE (n)-[:GENERATED]->(z)
    ',
{phase:'after'});
```

Which is supposed to catch the update event and, after the transaction that updates the *_executed* property commits, creates a new relationship with the updated node and the new node *z*.

And then, if I try to update this *_executed* property, for instance:

```
MATCH (a:TEST)
WHERE a.name = 'x'
SET a._executed = a._executed+1
```

Unless I terminate this query this never seems to end (the circular spinner of the neo4j desktop app stays there forever), and if I do terminate it, it will leave the graph in the same state it was before the update, except that the _executed property was indeed updated... But neither the new node or the new relation was created.

If this said trigger is in **"phase: before"** or if there are no new relations created in the trigger concerning the node updated (i.e. if there is no relation created using the node *n*), this has the expected behavior and all goes smoothly...

Can anyone help me understand what's causing this in **"phase: after"**?

Comment: What version of neo4j and APOC are you using? I tried your use case with neo4j 4.0.1 and APOC 4.0.0.4, and it worked fine (except that the obsolete `{assignedNodeProperties}` syntax had to be changed to `$assignedNodeProperties`). By the way, you should not be storing a native ID in a property, as the ID can be used by a different node once the original node is deleted. Besides, you can already use the `GENERATED` relationship to find the father anyway.

Comment: Hi @cybersam, and thanks for the quick reply. I was using neo4j 3.5.14 with APOC 3.5.0.9, but I just upgraded the versions to match yours, namely neo4j 4.0.1 with APOC 4.0.0.4, and it still doesn't work. I realized that I forgot to post a vital part of this simulation, which was the query that never ended... I have already edited the original post. To summarize, the trigger itself is accepted in `"phase: after"`, however, the query that updates the `_executed` property never ends.

Comment: I am facing the exactly same problem.
If I execute cypher in trigger, it completes instantly, but within trigger (phase 'after') it never completes.